# Align left but center content

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

I'm trying to align the text to the left but center the content as well. Its not working.

Like this: [image of the design I wish to accompolish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjgHZ.png).

Here is my PUG markup and I have placed the rest of the info on codepen.io:

```
section.team-section.section
    .container  
        .row.center-it
            .center-it.col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-8.col-lg-8.u-align--center
                h1.section__title.section__title--block
                    | <span class="u-display-block type---color-light-grey">Experienced.<br></span><span class="type--color-green u-display-block">Reliable.<br></span>
                    <span class="u-display-block type---color-light-grey">Commited.</span>
                p.section__description
                   | Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
```

> I'm using flexbox framework so that would have been too much to copy
>   and paste here.

**here is my full code on codepen.io, this link will provide all scss mark up:**
https://codepen.io/harp30/pen/GGbKdp?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without setting an explicit width on the `h1`, I'm not sure you can do this with flex properties. The easiest way to do this would be to add the following:

```
.center-it {
    text-align: center;
}

.section{
    padding: 10rem 0 0 0;

    &__title{
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
    }
}

p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

This will allow the width of the `h1` to match the content, centering it within its parent, then left-aligning the text inside the h1. You'll also need to re-align the text in the paragraph.

Comment: okay works like a charm. Thank you! Just confusing why its not working with flexbox..

Comment: The only issue you may encounter using `display: inline-block` is the added space beneath the `h1`. To counter, you can set `font-size: 0` on `.center-it` and re-apply the size to the `h1` and `p` tags.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `.section` has `padding: 10rem 0 0 0;` rule, which means, that you have only padding from top and not from bottom. To center the content, you can add the same padding from bottom:

```
.section {
    padding: 10rem 0;
}
```

The idea is to have the same paddings/margins from both, top and bottom. And to center the text in `<h1>` you can simply use `text-align: center` rule.

Here is the updated [**DEMO**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dKByPo?editors=1100).

Comment: okay thank you for helping, but don't want to make it text-align center but rather text-align: left but have content in the center of the page...

Comment: @Harpreet, looks like you've already got the answer for this separate question)